# How to pass uploaded files(images, pdf) and JSON data to the backend at the same time using fetch API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm using React JS as the frontend framework. I have a form with different inputs. Some of those are text inputs and the others are file uploads. Here's the post request.

```
        const formData = new FormData();
        const imgUpload = document.querySelector('#imgUpload');
        const mouUpload = document.querySelector('#mouUpload');
        
        //-------setting the form data----------
        formData.append('oName', formValues.oName);
        formData.append('oWeb', formValues.oWeb);
        formData.append('oVC', formValues.oVC);
        formData.append('oVP', formValues.oVP);
        formData.append('oImg', imgUpload.files[0]);
        formData.append('oMou', mouUpload.files[0]);
        

        //---------fetch post request--------------
        fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
          console.log('Success:', result);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error:', error);
        });
```

This is a successful post request and I can see this as the result.

[image]

But I want to be able to see **text input filed data** under **data** and the **file uploads** under **files** in this success result. I know that I'm passing those values to **formData** , I did that because I wanted to get **text input data** to be shown in the result somehow. How can I implement this ? Please guide me if I'm doing something wrong here. Appreciate your help.

Comment: How you put the data into `data` instead of into `form` is *entirely* dependant on your **server-side** code.

Comment: If I just pass ```body: JSON.stringify(data)``` as the body, I'm able to see form data under data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HTTP request body has to be encoded *somehow*. Then the server-side code has to decode it.

From your comments we can infer that if you encode the body as JSON then it will decode it and put it in `data`. If you encode it as multi-part, then it will decode it and put the files in `files` and the rest of the data in `forms`.

If you want it to put the rest of the data in `data` then you'll need to change the server-side code.

I'd just read it from `form` myself.